# Access - VBA - SQL Query for All Records

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

```
Date        Name    Charge
1/15/2015   Alpha   0
2/15/2015   Alpha   0
2/15/2015   Beta    0
2/15/2015   Gamma   2
3/15/2015   Gamma   3
3/15/2015   Alpha   5
4/15/2015   Beta    0
```

Above is a sample table in Access. My intent is to capture all unique Names that have strictly value 0 for 'Charge', but if any name has a non-zero value, then the query would not return the Name at all.
For example, based on sample data, a correctly write query would result in only "Beta" showing up.

How can a SQL query be written for the above requirements? Appreciate the help - thanks!

Comment: I'm updating this where instead of 0, I'm looking for charges strictly equal to 3.39. How would a SQL query be written? I realize SUM would not work for this request, and Access is limited in the number of functions available.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUM` along with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT Name
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Name
HAVING SUM(Charge) = 0
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/482861)</kbd>

Comment: Felix - this is great...thank you, but could greater flexibility be coded in? For example, assuming 5/15/2015 was a constant value, and the user entered "2", then the query would only apply to strictly data 2 months back, being from 3/15/15 onwards. Or if user entered "3", then the query would only apply to strictly data 3 months back, being from 2/15/15 onwards.

Comment: In following up, is there a simple way to include 2 conditions for the HAVING criteria? I'm looking for Sum(Charge) = 0 and Sum(Charge) = 5

Comment: I'm updating this where instead of 0, I'm looking for charges strictly equal to 3.39. How would a SQL query be written? I realize SUM would not work for this request, and Access is limited in the number of functions available.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may actually have the solution (below) being this to my own question. It's instead requesting user to enter start date & end date as inputs:

```
PARAMETERS [Start Date] DateTime, [End Date] DateTime;
SELECT tbl.Name
FROM tbl
WHERE ([tbl].[Date]>=[Start Date] And [tbl].[Date]<=[End Date])
GROUP BY tbl.Name
HAVING SUM(Charge) = 0;
```

Comment: I'm updating this where instead of 0, I'm looking for charges strictly equal to 3.39. How would a SQL query be written? I realize SUM would not work for this request, and Access is limited in the number of functions available.